# Security permissions on uploaded libraries

Tags: c#, security, dll, permissions

I am uploading DLLs **from client machines** to a server. These DLLs will be created and executed via **reflection**. Each DLL should have **read/write** on only **one** specific directory on the server. This directory is specific to the DLL.

I want a way of forcing the DLL to **only be able to access** its own specific directory. Since the DLLs are uploaded, I want to be able to assign this **permission dynamically**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you force the DLLs to use your API - for example via a shared object providing them with FileSystem-Access then you could just run the respective DLL in a separate AppDomain which you setup with a reduced PermissionSet (i.e. without File IO permission)...

This way .NET enforces the needed security and your API can provide any operation you want to restrict/log etc. like File IO...

Comment: I was unclear in my question, but your answer is indeed correct. It wont work for my specific case but it is a good solution and so i will accept it as such

Answer (score 0):

[Polaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Polaris_%28computer_security%29) allows sandboxing of windows applications, including the ability to run a process in such a way that initially it only has access to a subset of the file-system and can only gain access to other files via user-interaction with a file-chooser.

If your various DLLs can each be loaded and run in a separate process and communicate via the normal IPC mechanisms, this could work for you.

Comment: Where can we get Polaris?  I can't get it to come up in Google.

Comment: @Inuyasha, I don't see a link from the [project page](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/mmsl/projects/adv/polaris.html).  I would email the [captalk](http://www.eros-os.org/mailman/listinfo/cap-talk) mailing list which is frequented by a bunch of the Polaris principles including Alan Karp and Marc Stiegler.  The [original announcement of Polaris](http://www.eros-os.org/pipermail/cap-talk/2010-April/014191.html) is on that mailing list, and it includes a link.  I don't know whether that's still good.

Comment: @Inuyasha, Actually, a [more recent post](http://www.eros-os.org/pipermail/cap-talk/2010-April/014191.html) points to [github](https://github.com/raould/Polaris-Open-Source).  It's probably still worth sending a mail to that list though as there may be changes since the initial release not reflected on github.